# Elgg 1.7.7 Installation - Blank Page after Database Settings

Tags: php, mysql, elgg

I am trying to install elgg 1.7.7 in windows with Apache 2.2 and php 5.3, I have checked that mod_rewrite is working.

Now the issue is I am getting a blank page after submitting the database details.

can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have to manually edit the config to add the database connection settings.

Answer (score 0):

Elgg displays BLANK page, when there is error in the page, by Default Elgg hides all the Errors, you can enable them in .htaccess file i.e.

```
# hide errors, enable only if debug enabled
php_value display_errors 0
```

set "0" to "1"

Once enabled, you'll see the reason for the BLANK page.
Hope this helps..
Thanks

Also try clearing the simple cache that is in your data folder.